# Eval function not loading libraries in R

Tags: r

I am currently facing an issue with the `eval` function in R. In my real code, I have multiple libraries being loaded, but for simplicity, I will use `data.table` as an example.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
test_code <- "library(data.table); data.table(iris)"
new_env <- new.env(parent = baseenv())
eval(parse(text = test_code), envir = new_env)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Error in data.table(iris) : could not find function "data.table"
```

It seems like the `eval` function is not loading the `data.table` library in the new environment. I am not sure why this is happening as I expected the library to be loaded and the `data.table` function to be available in the new environment.

It's important to note that while this simplified example requires loading only one library, my actual project involves a significantly more complex and lengthy R `test_code`, with numerous libraries being loaded. As I cannot predict which libraries will need to be loaded, I would prefer if they could be automatically loaded upon evaluating the code.

---

**Edit**
The goal is to test if a codebase that is in principle self-sufficient operates correctly in a completely new environment. In other words, that it works from scratch.

More context:

I'm developing a Shiny app for data cleaning that also creates R code to replicate all actions performed in the app, including library loading. My aim is to test and evaluate this R code to verify if the resulting cleaned dataset matches the one from the Shiny app. Since the R code is generated dynamically, I don't know its contents in advance. Finally, I need to access and compare the cleaned dataset produced by the R code (accessible via `new_env$DT`) with the one generated through the app. The code replicate testing should be performed withing the Shiny app.

Comment: Great question... The answer is in here somewhere: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html

Comment: I think the problem is that `library()` loads namespaces onto the search list, not into an environment. Check out the output of `search()`. "Environments" hold your own objects and access functions by looking through the search list (starting at the position/parent defined, e.g., baseenv). Unless you use external tools or write code to monitor exactly how the search list is modified, the environments made with `new.env()` will be affected by any other code that affects the search list. Not sure how to help except to suggest running test code is separate R sessions (e.g., with Rscript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `new_env` environment has its parent set to `baseenv()`, and the parent of `baseenv()` is empty.  You didn't put any objects into `new_env`, so when you evaluate your expression in that environment, only objects in `baseenv()` will be found.  `library()` is a function in the base environment, so that doesn't trigger an error, but `library()` modifies the search list, not the base environment, so `data.table()` will never be found.

To know what to do to fix your code, I'd need to know what you intend it to do.

- If you just want access to the `data.table` function, you could leave the `new_env` definition as it is, but execute `data.table::data.table(iris)`.
- If you want the side effect of attaching `data.table` to the search list and want to evaluate your expression without the prefix, you could set the parent to `globalenv()` instead.  However, that would allow a user to put a function named `data.table` into the global environment and it would take precedence over the one in the `data.table` package.
- If you want the side effect of changing the search list but want to skip over the global environment, I think it's messy: the first entry in the search list is the parent of `globalenv()`, but `library(data.table)` might change that.  So you could use `library(data.table, pos = 3)`, but if you want to execute exactly the code you showed us, I think you can't do it with a single specification for `envir`.  You'd need to parse the code and evaluate the expressions one at a time, each one using `envir = parent.env(globalenv())`.  For example:

```r
test_code <- "library(data.table); print(data.table(iris))"

new_env <- new.env(parent = parent.env(globalenv()))

exprs <- parse(text = test_code)

for (i in seq_along(exprs)) {
  eval(exprs[[i]], envir = new_env)
  parent.env(new_env) <- parent.env(globalenv())
}
```

You said in a comment that "The code is supposed to be self-sufficient, so the idea is to test the code in a completely new environment and ensure that everything works as intended."  In that case, I wouldn't use my sample code, which evaluates it in a very strange way.  You should do what `R CMD check` does, which is to start a new R process to run the tests by sourcing a file holding the code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The code is supposed to be self-sufficient, so the idea is to test the code in a completely new environment and ensure that everything works as intended.

Comment: I've added some advice for that case.

Comment: I edited my post to provide some extra context

Comment: I don't know the limitations on Shiny apps, but if you can't start a new R process to run the test code, I think your problem will be very difficult to do.  What you are trying to do sounds like setting up a virtual R environment within R.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Didn't know how to label it. I'll make a related post specifically about setting up a virtual R environment within R using Shiny. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As user2554330 said, it's not at all clear why you want to do this or what final outcome you want.

The simplest method I can think of is to do a test each time you want to load a library, do

```
if( class(try(library(whatever_lib)) == 'try_error') install.packages(whatever_lib)
```

or something more detailed using `tryCatch`

#EDIT
or maybe just

```
if(!require(whatever_lib))  install.packages(whatever_lib)
```

Comment: The challenge is that the code is dynamical and I don't know in advance which libraries will be requiered. I'd rather avoid a solution in which I have to explicitly load every package.

Comment: @mat first of all I'm talking about **installing** the library in your new environment. You can then call explicit functions as desired.   Second, you can always extract the necessary library name as a char string and feed that to `library("whatever_lib")` . Only run my code snippet if your  `whatever_lib::some_func` fails (preferably via a `try`